# Move file with file-adapter with SI

Tags: java, spring-integration

Move file with file-adapter
Hi
I'd like to move file in sucess folder after it'is consumed or in failed
folder when there is the problem.

Around I found different example but  I could not figure out an easy
solution to move file with file-adapter

Probably I have problem in using Spring Expression Language but if i use

```
<int:poller default="true" fixed-delay="50"/>
<bean id="pseudoTransactionManager" class="org.springframework.integration.transaction.PseudoTransactionManager" />

<int:channel id="committedChannel"/>
<int:channel id="rolledBackChannel"/>

<int-file:inbound-channel-adapter channel="input" directory="target/input" filename-pattern="*">
 <int:poller fixed-rate="500">
           <int:transactional transaction-manager="pseudoTransactionManager" synchronization-factory="syncFactory" />
 </int:poller>
</int-file:inbound-channel-adapter>

<int:transaction-synchronization-factory id="syncFactory">
   <int:after-commit expression="payload.renameTo('/success/' + payload.name)" channel="committedChannel" />
   <int:after-rollback expression="payload.renameTo('/failed/' + payload.name)" channel="rolledBackChannel" />
</int:transaction-synchronization-factory>

<int:service-activator input-channel="input" ref="sampleEndpoint" output-channel="output"/>

<int:channel id="output"/>
<int-file:outbound-channel-adapter channel="output" directory="target/output"/>
```

I retrive the following error 
`Method call: Method renameTo(java.lang.String) cannot be found on  java.io.File type correctly` that is correct cause the method doesn't exists

if i use payload.remove() I remove file not move.
if I don't use remove file it is not remove from src

I think that it's a dummy configuration or a simple use of SpEL but ... I can't figure out a linear solution

Thanks

martin

Answer (score 1):

There's a bug in the sample; it should be...

```
<int:after-commit expression="payload.renameTo(new java.io.File('/success/' + payload.name))" channel="committedChannel" />
<int:after-rollback expression="payload.renameTo(new java.io.File('/failed/' + payload.name))" channel="rolledBackChannel" />
```